# Se me presenta un problema en una consulta en postgresql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Quiero hacer un filtrado por numero de identif pero este es de tipo numeric y el like no lo acepta como puedo hacer? la consulta es esta `"SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE identif LIKE '_%'";` donde identif es de tipo numeric

Comment: quiero hacer una búsqueda filtrada en java y mi tabla en postgresql tiene 8 campos de los cuales esta el identif que es la cedula entonces en mi buscador quiero que el usuario coloque un numero y este lo busque en los registros pero se me presenta ese problema @sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes convertir el campo a un `varchar` usando un `CAST` para poder usar el operador `LIKE`:

```
select *
  from cliente
 where cast(identif as varchar) LIKE '123%'
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/SWAT71124)</kbd>

Tristemente, si tenías un índice definido para la columna `identif`, la conversión de tipo impedirá que se pueda usar el indice para mejor rendimiento.

Si el rendimiento es un problema, tal vez valga la pena modificar el tipo de la columna para que sea alfanumérico de una vez. Siendo que se trata de una cédula, no es necesario que el campo sea numérico, ya que no necesitas efectuar aritmética. Un campo alfanumérico tiene más sentido en tu caso.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió